# Non blocking socket get errno without consume data?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, network-programming

Found this routine to check the socket states.

```
ssize_t rret = recv(fd, buf, 1, MSG_PEEK)
// check rret errno
```

My question is, what will happen when socket has pending data and error at the same time? How to deal with a `write` caused error.

Comment: All socket errors except `EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK` are fatal to the connection and cause all pending data to be discarded. `EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK` arise in non-blocking mode and should cause you to use `select()/poll()/epoll()` to establish when the operation would next succeed.

Comment: There is nothing about this question that is unclear or requires code.

Comment: @user207421 Sorry for unclear, I updated my question.

Comment: There is nothing unclear here. I understood, and I answered. But your code is wrong., You must store the return value in an `int`. Otherwise the comparison to -1 can never succeed.

Comment: ssize_t recv(int socket, void *buffer, size_t length, int flags);

@user207421 the declaration

Comment: I know what it says, but you still have to be able to check it against -1, so you receive it into an `int` and then typecast it if it is positive.